# When does a universal cover exists for a Topological Space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

My question is: What are the conditions that a topological space must satisfy to admit a universal cover?
And give me a counter example of a space that doesn't admit a universal cover, and which assumptions are not satisfied.

Comment: What is your definition of a universal cover for a general space $X$? $p: Y \to X$ continuous and onto and every $x \in X$ has a neighbourhood $O_x$ such that $p^{-1}[O_x]$ is a disjoint union of open sets $U_i$ of $X$ such that $p\restriction_{U_i}: U_i \to O_x$ is a homeomorphism, but what more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the classification of coverings says that a connected space admits a universal cover if and only if it is locally pathconnected and semilocally simply connected.

The [hawaiian earrings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) are not semilocally simply connected, hence don’t admit a universal covering.

Comment: Nothing in the linked article seems to imply that the mentioned result is an "if and only if".

Comment: In fact, depending on your definition of "universal covering", there can exist a (path-)connected spaces which admit universal covers but are not locally path-connected. If with "universal covering" you mean "simply connected covering", then any simply connected, non-locally-path-connected space, like Warsaw circle, will do.

Comment: @Wojowu Maybe I was misinterpreting what my professor told me. Topology gets me every time with its „depending on your definition“... I cannot delete my answer though, since it is accepted.